I am using react-router-dom. Can I update path dynamically in react?
I am trying to update the path dynamically with api call. in router path. when I click the nav menu , first time it loads perfectly. but if I refresh it throws 404 error?
    <Routes>
      <Route path={`${item.path}`} element={<Platform />} />
      <Route path={`${item2.path}`} element={<Licensing />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>

IS there any way to fix this?

On the top of my head, i would say the API call either isn't happening on refresh or there is a delay between the rendering of the links and the API call result.
Will need more information like where is this component and on which page you are when you are refreshing the page.

Where those item and item2 come from?

Need more details. Show us rest of the code and the complete error message

Please [edit] to clarify what "update path dynamically in react" means specifically to you, and to include a complete [mcve]. It's unclear what any issue or problem is. Take the full [tour] and review Help/How to Ask for additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

Like abhishekti said, I think that when you refresh, React renders your component before the API calls is completed (or even maybe started).
I see 2 options to solve your issue:

add a loading effect directly in your component containing the Router (you can use suspense if your API call library manages it or manual otherwise with a React useState). You hide the component Router until you fetched the urls.
you keep the urls in the session storage/local storage/cookies so that the app remembers the urls. I gave the list in the order that I consider the safer for your use case.

